# Display Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy Data on Front End Using Only a Plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Can anyone suggest a good plugin-based, as opposed to template or theme-based, solution for the following that doesn't rely on shortcodes?

I have a plugin that creates a custom post type and four custom taxonomies.

The custom post type has the `/songs` slug.

The custom taxonomies have the following slugs:

`/songs/genres`

`/songs/eras`

`/songs/venue`

`/songs/artists`

My question is, how do I get the following URLs to show my custom content IN TABLE FORM without messing with custom templates or shortcodes?

`/songs` - show a table of all songs in the database sorted by song name

`/songs/<song-name>` - show a table of data connected to this song

`/songs/genres` - show a table of all genres in the database sorted by genre name

`/songs/eras` - show a table of all eras in the database sorted by era name

`/songs/venue` - show a table of all venues in the database sorted by venue name

`/songs/artists` - show a table of all artists in the database sorted by artist name

`/songs/genres/<genre>` - show a table of songs, sorted by name, with this genre

`/songs/eras/<era>` - show a table of songs, sorted by name, with this era

`/songs/venue/<venues>` - show a table of songs, sorted by name, with this venue

`/songs/artists/<artist>` - show a table of songs, sorted by name, with this artist

*Example table I'd like on every page:*

```
Song Name | Artist  | Genre  | Era  | Venue
--------------------------------------------
song1     | artist1 | genre1 | era1 | venue1
song2     | artist2 | genre2 | era2 | venue2
```

I've figured out how to do this using custom templates, but these templates won't work with all themes. The custom templates would have to be re-coded for any theme other than the one I'm using for development.

In my reading on this issue, I've come to understand that it's not a good idea to put design code into plugins. But, if this is the case, how can I be sure my custom content gets displayed appropriately across many different themes? I think what I'm missing is how custom post types and custom taxonomies can be portable across themes.

If I haven't provided enough information, let me know what more I need to share.

Thanks.

Comment: Can Mark Kaplun, Pieter Goosen, TheDeadMedic, mrwweb, or ialocin explain to me in more detail how this is off-topic? How else should I ask this. The reasoning for the hold question in order to learn more about writing custom post types and custom taxonomies in WordPress plugins? As a new person to this community, I find this kind of thing and the reason given for it to be off-putting, to say the least.

Comment: **Tried to edit to fix the previous comment but it was past the 5 minute time limit** Can Mark Kaplun, Pieter Goosen, TheDeadMedic, mrwweb, or ialocin explain to me in more detail how this is off-topic? How else should I ask this in order to learn more about writing custom post types and custom taxonomies in WordPress plugins? As a new person to this community, I find this kind of thing and the reason given for it to be off-putting, to say the least.

Comment: Hi! I think you got couple angles wrong, which skewed perception of your question. First, opening with "suggest / plugin-based" provokes knee-jerk looking-for-plugin impression. "I have trouble developing following solution..." would come across much better. Also your questions has excessive amount of detail, which drowns the _conceptual_ part of it, which you actually looking to resolve. I am reopening, but would advise to edit it in light of this. :)

Comment: I appreciate this. Thanks. I think those who judged this to be off-topic for that reason should actually read questions before marking them a certain way. Regarding the amount of detail ... I included as much detail as possible because I'm not sure what the main issue is, since my question deals with multiple issues. I guess if I already knew the answer to my question I'd be able to know exactly how much detail I should put into the question. I've also seen many questions that didn't have enough detail and I was attempting to avoid that situation. Thanks for opening it back up, though.

Comment: If you have multiple issues then _ask multiple questions_. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you suggest the questions I should ask? I don't know enough about what I'm asking (which is why I'm asking) in order to know what the multiple questions should be.

Comment: I cannot take questions out of your mind and write them. :) Work through [How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and related help center articles for starters.

Comment: This question should have stayed closed, :-). It is still way too broad. Styling issues is also off topic. Styling is theme territory, not plugins, and that is where your tables should be. The best possible solution is a shortcode if you need this to be in a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there is no way to do what I'm asking, at least, there's no simple/easy way. Pieter Goosen writes in their comment above:

> Styling is theme territory, not
>   plugins, and that is where your tables should be. The best possible
>   solution is a shortcode if you need this to be in a plugin.

I would add to this that custom templates are also an option, but further blur the line between themes and plugins.

The WordPress documentation isn't clear on this. It seems to be a grey area.

WordPress allows us to create custom post types and custom taxonomies but because that data can be anything, there's no standardized way of using that data across themes other than to treat it like any other post, category, or tag ... even if the data doesn't make sense to be treated that way.

**Aside:** *As a first time questioner, I'm disappointed by the regulars I've interacted with here so far and hope that my future questions are either answered/commented on by more open and welcoming folks or are not answered/commented on at all. I wish someone who had experience writing a plugin with similar functionality would've answered. But, since this is my first question and it is broad, it's likely my fault. It's another RTFM situation. :( I was hoping the WordPress developer community was more welcoming than that.*

Comment: Just on your **Aside**. If I came across as being rude, sorry about that. As already pointed out by me and @Rarst, your question is way to broad. We have a one question per post policy. You had multiple issues here. These types of questions are usually ignored and left without an answer. To be honest, I don't answer questions with multiple issues. Read through [help] and visit the [tour] page and read [ask] to avoid your question/s being "ignored" in future. I hope you can put this behind you and be a constructive member of this site :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think it was confusing because of the initial reason the question was put on hold and the willingness for you all to comment but not attempt an answer. I appreciate your follow-up with me on this and will do my best to utilize the resources you mention here for future questions.